# SetTimeout executing but no delay

Tags: javascript

I am developing a Binary Tree Search visualization program using JSAV library. The problem is that all the nodes are getting highlighted instantly and I want to show it step by step without any pressing of button again and again.

I tried to highlight a node and use timeout function to stop the execution for few seconds and then unhighlight the node and then proceed with next selected node, however there is no effect at all. Can anybody suggest me what can I do to modify my program to incorporate this type of feature?

Code: (Uses JSAV library)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/JSAV.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Binary Tree Page</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.transit.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/JSAV.js"></script>
    <Script src="lib/includeall.js"></Script>


<style>
    .highlight
    {

        background-color: blue;
    }
    .unhighlight
    {

        background-color: white;

    }
    #av {
      width: 98%;
      position: relative;
    }
    .jsavcounter {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
    }
    .jsavtree {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
    }
    svg {
      height: 600px;
    }
    path {
      pointer-events: visible;
    }


    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="av">

    </div>
<script>

    var jsav=new JSAV("av");
    var bt=jsav.ds.binarytree();

addNode(bt,20);
addNode(bt,5);
addNode(bt,40);
addNode(bt,50);
addNode(bt,60);
addNode(bt,70);
addNode(bt,4);

function donothing()
{

}
    function searchBinarytree()
    {
        var value=parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);

        var test=bt.root();

        while(test!=null)
        {
          test.addClass("highlight");
          setTimeout(donothing,20000);




            if(test.value()==value)

            {
                break ;

            }

            if(test.value()<=value)
            {
            test.toggleClass("unhighlight");
            test=test.right();
            }
            else

            {test.toggleClass("unhighlight");
            test=test.left();
            }


            bt.layout();
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="valuebox">
    Value to search:<input id="value" type="text"> <button type="button" onclick="searchBinarytree()"> Search</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `setTimeout` anywhere (except in the question).

Comment: Please show your example with the `setTimeout` otherwise we can't help you to figure out what's the problem

Comment: No `setTimeout` and very bad indented

Comment: Included in the code

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is calling `donothing` which is "doing nothing". You should instead call the function you want repeated from within setTimeout. I assume you expect it to pause at that call, but that's not how setTimeout works. More info can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Something like this should work (not tested)

```
var test;

function searchBinarytree() {    
  test = bt.root();    
  test.addClass("highlight");
  setTimeout(updateNode, 20000);
}

function updateNode() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value);

  if (test != null) {

    if (test.value() != value) {    
      test.removeClass("highlight");

      if (test.value() <= value) {
        test = test.right();
      } else {
        test = test.left();
      }

      if (test != null) {
        test.addClass("highlight");
      }

      setTimeout(updateNode, 20000);
    }

    bt.layout();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks H77 for the suggestion, but the code also highlights the Node whose value matches immediately. What I require is highlight root, calculate the next node,unhighlight root and then highlight the selected node so one can get feel of how algorithm is moving.

Comment: Thank you so much for help but it still directly highlights the Node whose value is matched.Is there any solution?

Comment: Updated once again. Please check.

Comment: Thanks a lot H77, Works flawlessly. Can you explain what you did?

Comment: Previously you were highlighting and then removing the highlight immediately afterwards. What I've done is remove the highlight of the previous node during the next call to updateNode. This leaves a 20 second gap between highlighting of nodes.

Comment: @user3930213 please accept the answer if it helped solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure that it's your issue but:

When you use setTimeout use it like that

```
setTimeout(yourFunction, timeout);
```

not

```
setTimeout(yourFunction(), timeout);
```

you have to pass the function to be invoked, you don't invoke the function

Comment: Yes, although you can't use the keyword `function` here, since the JS engine will think that's a syntax error.